# How to store large size texts in a TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, textview

I am currently making an application showing text from our holy book. As i am storing all the verses in a a single TextView, upon running instead of that TextView it shows STRING_TOO_LARGE.
I am using a string resource which contains thousands of lines of text and then storing it in  TextView.
Any fix for this would solve my issue.

Also I am confused on how to show the verses in a particular format like in a poem with one line ending with a comma and next line with a fullstop.

this is my xml file containing the TextView with id secondary_activity_bani_text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondaryActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_secondary_bani_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/raaj___9"
        android:text="ਜਪੁਜੀ ਸਾਹਿਬ"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_secondary_bani_name">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/secondary_activity_bani_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/japji_sahib"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is my string resource

```
<string name="jaap_sahib">ੴ
ਸਤਿਗੁਰ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ॥
ਸੀ੍ ਵਾਹਿਗੁਰੂ ਜੀ ਕੀ ਫਤਹ ॥
||ਜਾਪੁ ||
ਸ੍ੀ ਮੁਖਵਾਕ ਪਾਤਿਸਾਹੀ ੧੦ ॥
ਛਪੈ ਛੰਦ ॥ ਤ੍ਵ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ॥
ਚੱਕ੍ ਚਿਹਨ ਅਰੁ ਬਰਨ ਜਾਤਿ ਅਰੁ ਪਾਤਿ ਨਹਿਨ ਜਿਹ ॥
ਰੂਪ ਰੰਗ ਅਰੁ ਰੇਖ ਭੇਖ ਕੋਊ ਕਹਿ ਨ ਸਕਤ ਕਿਹ ॥
ਅਚਲ ਮੂਰਤਿ ਅਨਭਉ ਪ੍ਰਕਾਸ ਅਮਿਤੋਜਿ ਕਹਿੱਜੈ ॥
ਕੋਟਿ ਇੰਦ੍ ਇੰਦ੍ਰਾਣਿ ਸਾਹਿ ਸਾਹਾਣਿ ਗਣਿਜੈ ॥
ਤਿ੍ਭਵਣ ਮਹੀਪ ਸੁਰ ਨਰ ਅਸੁਰ ਨੇਤ ਨੇਤ ਬਨ ਤਿ੍ਣ ਕਹਤ ॥
ਤ੍ਵ ਸਰਬ ਨਾਮ ਕਥੈ ਕਵਨ ਕਰਮ ਨਾਮ ਬਰਨਤ ਸੁਮਤਿ ॥੧॥
ਭੁਜੰਗ ਪ੍ਰਯਾਤ ਛੰਦ ॥
ਨਮਸਤ੍ਵੰ ਅਕਾਲੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤ੍ਵੰ ਕ੍ਰਿਪਾਲੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਨੂਪੇ ॥੨॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਭੇਖੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਲੇਖੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਕਾਏ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਜਾਏ॥੩॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਗੰਜੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਭੰਜੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਨਾਮੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਠਾਮੇ ॥੪॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਕਰਮੰ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਧਰਮੰ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਨਾਮੰ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਧਾਮੰ ॥੫॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਜੀਤੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਭੀਤੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਬਾਹੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਢਾਹੇ ॥੬॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਨੀਲੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਨਾਦੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਛੇਦੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਗਾਧੇ ॥੭॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਗੰਜੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਭੰਜੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਉਦਾਰੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਪਾਰੇ ॥੮॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਸੁ ਏਕੈ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਨੇਕੈ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਭੂਤੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਜੂਪੇ ॥੯॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਕਰਮੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਭਰਮੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਦੇਸੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਭੇਸੇ ॥੧੦॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਨਾਮੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਕਾਮੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਧਾਤੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਘਾਤੇ ॥੧੧॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਧੂਤੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਭੂਤੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਲੋਕੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਸੋਕੇ ॥੧੨॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਤਾਪੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਥਾਪੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਤ੍ਰਿਮਾਨੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨਿਧਾਨੇ ॥੧੩॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਗਾਹੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਬਾਹੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਤ੍ਰਿਬਰਗੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਸਰਗੇ ॥੧੪॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਪ੍ਰਭੋਗੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਸੁ ਜੋਗੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਰੰਗੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਭੰਗੇ ॥੧੫॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਗੰਮੇ ॥ ਨਮਸੱਤਸਤੁ ਰੰਮੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਜਲਾਸਰੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨਿਰਾਸਰੇ ॥੧੬॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਜਾਤੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਪਾਤੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਮਜਬੇ ॥ ਨਮਸੱਤਸਤੁ ਅਜਬੇ ॥੧੭॥
ਅਦੇਸੰ ਅਦੇਸੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਭੇਸੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਧਾਮੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਬਾਮੇ ॥੧੮॥
ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਕਾਲੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਦਿਆਲੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਭੂਪੇ ॥੧੯॥
ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਖਾਪੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਥਾਪੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਕਾਲੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਪਾਲੇ ॥੨੦॥
ਨਮਸੱਤਸਤੁ ਦੇਵੈ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਭੇਵੈ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਜਨਮੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਸੁ ਬਨਮੇ ॥੨੧॥
ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਗਉਨੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਭਉਨੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਰੰਗੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਭੰਗੇ ॥੨੨॥
ਨਮੋ ਕਾਲ ਕਾਲੇ ॥ ਨਮਸੱਤਸਤੁ ਦਿਆਲੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਬਰਨੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਮਰਨੇ ॥੨੩॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਜਰਾਰੰ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਕ੍ਰਿਤਾਰੰ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਧੰਧੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਤ ਅਬੰਧੇ ॥੨੪॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਸਾਕੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਬਾਕੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਰਹੀਮੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਕਰੀਮੇ ॥੨੫॥
ਨਮਸਤੰ ਅਨੰਤੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਮਹੰਤੇ ॥ ਨਮਸੱਤਸਤੁ ਰਾਗੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਸੁਹਾਗੇ ॥੨੬॥
ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਸੋਖੰ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਪੋਖੰ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਕਰਤਾ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਹਰਤਾ ॥੨੭॥
ਨਮੋ ਜੋਗ ਜੋਗੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਭੋਗ ਭੋਗੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਦਿਆਲੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਪਾਲੇ ॥੨੮॥

ਚਾਚਰੀ ਛੰਦ ॥ ਤ੍ਵ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ॥
ਅਰੂਪ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਨੂਪ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਜੂ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੂ ਹੈਂ ॥੨੯॥
ਅਲੇਖ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੇਖ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਨਾਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਕਾਮ ਹੈਂ ॥੩੦॥
ਅਧੇ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੇ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਜੀਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੀਤ ਹੈਂ ॥੩੧॥
ਤ੍ਰਿਮਾਨ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਨਿਧਾਨ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਤ੍ਰਿਬਰਗ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਸਰਗ ਹੈਂ ॥੩੨॥
ਅਨੀਲ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਨਾਦਿ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਜੇ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਜਾਦਿ ਹੈਂ ॥੩੩॥
ਅਜਨਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਬਰਨ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੂਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭਰਨ ਹੈਂ ॥੩੪॥
ਅਗੰਜ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੰਜ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਝੂਝ ਹੈਂ॥ ਅਝੰਝ ਹੈਂ ॥੩੫॥
ਅੱਮੀਕ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਰਫ਼ੀਕ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਧੰਧ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਬੰਧ ਹੈਂ ॥੩੬॥
ਨ੍ਰਿਬੂਝ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਸੂਝ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਕਾਲ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਜਾਲ ਹੈਂ ॥੩੭॥
ਅਲਾਹ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਜਾਹ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਨੰਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਮਹੰਤ ਹੈਂ ॥੩੮॥
ਅਲੀਕ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਨ੍ਰਿਸਰੀਕ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਨ੍ਰਿਲੰਭ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਸੰਭ ਹੈਂ ॥੩੯॥
ਅਗੰਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਜੰਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੂਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਛੂਤ ਹੈਂ ॥੪੦॥
ਅਲੋਕ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਸੋਕ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਕਰਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭਰਮ ਹੈਂ ॥੪੧॥
ਅਜੀਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੀਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਬਾਹ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਗਾਹ ਹੈਂ ॥੪੨॥
ਅਮਾਨ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਨਿਧਾਨ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਨੇਕ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਫਿਰਿ ੲੇਕ ਹੈਂ ॥੪੩॥
ਭੁਜੰਗ ਪ੍ਰਯਾਤ ਛੰਦ ॥

ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਮਾਨੇ ॥ ਸਮਸਤੀ ਨਿਧਾਨੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਦੇਵ ਦੇਵੇ ॥ ਅਭੇਖੀ ਅਭੇਵੇ ॥੪੪॥
ਨਮੋ ਕਾਲ ਕਾਲੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਪਾਲੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਗਉਣੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਭਉਣੇ ॥੪੫॥
ਅਨੰਗੀ ਅਨਾਥੇ ॥ ਨ੍ਰਿਸੰਗੀ ਪ੍ਰਮਾਥੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਭਾਨ ਭਾਨੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਮਾਨ ਮਾਨੇ ॥੪੬॥
ਨਮੋ ਚੰਦ੍ਰ ਚੰਦ੍ਰੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਭਾਨ ਭਾਨੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਗੀਤ ਗੀਤੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਤਾਨ ਤਾਨੇ ॥੪੭॥
ਨਮੋ ਨ੍ਰਿੱਤ ਨ੍ਰਿੱਤੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਨਾਦ ਨਾਦੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਪਾਨ ਪਾਨੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਬਾਦ ਬਾਦੇ ॥੪੮॥
ਅਨੰਗੀ ਅਨਾਮੇ ॥ ਸਮਸਤੀ ਸਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਪ੍ਰਭੰਗੀ ਪ੍ਰਮਾਥੇ ॥ ਸਮਸਤੀ ਬਿਭੂਤੇ ॥੪੯॥
ਕਲੰਕੰ ਬਿਨਾ ਨੇ ਕਲੰਕੀ ਸਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਰਾਜ ਰਾਜੇਸ੍ਵਰੰ ਪਰਮ ਰੂਪੇ ॥੫੦॥
ਨਮੋ ਜੋਗ ਜੋਗੇਸ੍ਵਰੰ ਪਰਮ ਸਿੱਧੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਰਾਜ ਰਾਜੇਸ੍ਵਰੰ ਪਰਮ ਬ੍ਰਿਧੇ ॥੫੧॥
ਨਮੋ ਸਸਤ੍ਰ ਪਾਣੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਅਸਤ੍ਰ ਮਾਣੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਪਰਮ ਗਿਆਤਾ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਲੋਕ ਮਾਤਾ ॥੫੨॥
ਅਭੇਖੀ ਅਭਰਮੀ ਅਭੋਗੀ ਅਭੁਗਤੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਜੋਗ ਜੋਗੇਸ੍ਵਰੰ ਪਰਮ ਜੁਗਤੇ ॥੫੩॥
ਨਮੋ ਨਿੱਤ ਨਾਰਾਇਣੇ ਕ੍ਰੂਰ ਕਰਮੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਪ੍ਰੇਤ ਅਪ੍ਰੇਤ ਦੇਵੇ ਸੁਧਰਮੇ ॥੫੪॥
ਨਮੋ ਰੋਗ ਹਰਤਾ ਨਮੋ ਰਾਗ ਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਾਹ ਸਾਹੰ ਨਮੋ ਭੂਪ ਭੂਪੇ ॥੫੫॥
ਨਮੋ ਦਾਨ ਦਾਨੇ ਨਮੋ ਮਾਨ ਮਾਨੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਰੋਗ ਰੋਗੇ ਨਮਸਤੰ ਇਸਨਾਨੰ ॥੫੬॥
ਨਮੋ ਮੰਤ੍ਰ ਮੰਤ੍ਰੰ ਨਮੋ ਜੰਤ੍ਰ ਜੰਤ੍ਰੰ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਇਸਟ ਇਸਟੇ ਨਮੋ ਤੰਤ੍ਰ ਤੰਤ੍ਰੰ ॥੫੭॥
ਸਦਾ ਸਚਦਾਨੰਦ ਸਰਬੰ ਪ੍ਰਣਾਸੀ ॥ ਅਨੂਪੇ ਅਰੂਪੇ ਸਮਸਤੁਿਲ ਨਿਵਾਸੀ ॥੫੮॥
ਸਦਾ ਸਿਧਦਾ ਬੁਧਦਾ ਬ੍ਰਿਧ ਕਰਤਾ ॥ ਅਧੋ ਉਰਧ ਅਰਧੰ ਅਘੰ ਓਘ ਹਰਤਾ ॥੫੯॥
ਪਰਮ ਪਰਮ ਪਰਮੇਸ੍ਵਰੰ ਪ੍ਰੋਛ ਪਾਲੰ॥ ਸਦਾ ਸਰਬਦਾ ਸਿੱਧਿ ਦਾਤਾ ਦਿਆਲੰ ॥੬੦॥
ਅਛੇਦੀ ਅਭੇਦੀ ਅਨਾਮੰ ਅਕਾਮੰ ॥ ਸਮਸਤੋ ਪਰਾਜੀ ਸਮਸਤਸਤੁ ਧਾਮੰ ॥੬੧॥
ਤੇਰਾ ਜੋਰੁ ॥ ਚਾਚਰੀ ਛੰਦ ॥
ਜਲੇ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਥਲੇ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੀਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੇ ਹੈਂ ॥ ॥੬੨॥
ਪ੍ਰਭੂ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਜੂ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਦੇਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੇਸ ਹੈਂ ॥੬੩॥
ਭੁਜੰਗ ਪ੍ਰਯਾਤ ਛੰਦ ॥
ਅਗਾਧੇ ਅਬਾਧੇ ॥ ਅਨੰਦੀ ਸਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਮਾਨੇ ॥ ਸਮਸਤੀ ਨਿਧਾਨੇ ॥੬੪॥
ਨਮਸਤ੍ਵੰ ਨ੍ਰਿਨਾਥੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤ੍ਵੰ ਪ੍ਰਮਾਥੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤ੍ਵੰ ਅਗੰਜੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤ੍ਵੰ ਅਭੰਜੇ ॥੬੫॥
ਨਮਸਤ੍ਵੰ ਅਕਾਲੇ ॥ ਨਮਸਤ੍ਵੰ ਅਪਾਲੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਦੇਸੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਭੇਸੇ ॥੬੬॥
ਨਮੋ ਰਾਜ ਰਾਜੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਾਜ ਸਾਜੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸ਼ਾਹ ਸ਼ਾਹੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਮਾਹ ਮਾਹੇ ॥੬੭॥
ਨਮੋ ਗੀਤ ਗੀਤੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਪ੍ਰੀਤ ਪ੍ਰੀਤੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਰੋਖ ਰੋਖੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸੋਖ ਸੋਖੇ ॥੬੮॥
ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਰੋਗੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਭੋਗੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਜੀਤੰ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਭੀਤੰ ॥੬੯॥
ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਗਿਆਨੰ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਪਰਮ ਤਾਨੰ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਮੰਤ੍ਰੰ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਜੰਤ੍ਰੰ ॥੭੦॥
ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਦ੍ਰਿੱਸੰ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਕ੍ਰਿੱਸੰ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਸਰਬ ਰੰਗੇ ॥ ਤ੍ਰਿਭੰਗੀ ਅਨੰਗੇ ॥੭੧॥
ਨਮੋ ਜੀਵ ਜੀਵੰ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਬੀਜ ਬੀਜੇ ॥ ਅਖਿੱਜੇ ਅਭਿੱਜੇ ॥ ਸਮਸਤੰ ਪ੍ਰਸਿੱਜੇ ॥੭੨॥
ਕ੍ਰਿਪਾਲੰ ਸਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਕੁਕਰਮੰ ਪ੍ਰਣਾਸੀ ॥ ਸਦਾ ਸਰਬਦਾ ਰਿਧਿ ਸਿਧੰ ਨਿਵਾਸੀ ॥੭੩॥
ਚਰਪਟ ਛੰਦ ॥ ਤ੍ਵ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ॥
ਅੰਮ੍ਰਿਤ ਕਰਮੇ ॥ ਅੰਬ੍ਰਿਤ ਧਰਮੇ ॥ ਅਖੱਲ ਜੋਗੇ ॥ ਅਚੱਲ ਭੋਗੇ ॥੭੪॥
ਅਚੱਲ ਰਾਜੇ ॥ ਅਟੱਲ ਸਾਜੇ ॥ ਅਖੱਲ ਧਰਮੰ ॥ ਅਲੱਖ ਕਰਮੰ ॥੭੫॥
ਸਰਬੰ ਦਾਤਾ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਗਿਆਤਾ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਭਾਨੇ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਮਾਨੇ ॥੭੬॥
ਸਰਬੰ ਪ੍ਰਾਣੰ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਤ੍ਰਾਣੰ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਭੁਗਤਾ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਜੁਗਤਾ ॥੭੭॥
ਸਰਬੰ ਦੇਵੰ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਭੇਵੰ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਕਾਲੇ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਪਾਲੇ ॥੭੮॥
ਰੂਆਲ ਛੰਦ ॥ ਤ੍ਵ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ॥
ਆਦਿ ਰੂਪ ਅਨਾਦਿ ਮੂਰਤਿ ਅਜੋਨਿ ਪੁਰਖ ਅਪਾਰ ॥
ਸਰਬ ਮਾਨ ਤ੍ਰਿਮਾਨ ਦੇਵ ਅਭੇਵ ਆਦਿ ਉਦਾਰ ॥
ਸਰਬ ਪਾਲਕ ਸਰਬ ਘਾਲਕ ਸਰਬ ਕੋ ਪੁਨਿ ਕਾਲ ॥
ਜੱਤ੍ਰ ਤੱਤ੍ਰ ਬਿਰਾਜਹੀ ਅਵਧੂਤ ਰੂਪ ਰਿਸਾਲ ॥੭੯॥
ਨਾਮ ਠਾਮ ਨ ਜਾਤਿ ਜਾਕਰ ਰੂਪ ਰੰਗ ਨ ਰੇਖ ॥
ਆਦਿ ਪੁਰਖ ਉਦਾਰ ਮੂਰਤਿ ਅਜੋਨਿ ਆਦਿ ਅਸੇਖ ॥
ਦੇਸ ਔਰ ਨ ਭੇਸ ਜਾਕਰ ਰੂਪ ਰੇਖ ਨ ਰਾਗ ॥
ਜੱਤ੍ਰ ਤੱਤ੍ਰ ਦਿਸਾ ਵਿਸਾ ਹੁਇ ਫੈਲਿਓ ਅਨੁਰਾਗ ॥੮੦॥
ਨਾਮ ਕਾਮ ਬਿਹੀਨ ਪੇਖਤ ਧਾਮ ਹੂੰ ਨਹਿ ਜਾਹਿ ॥
ਸਰਬ ਮਾਨ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਮਾਨ ਸਦੈਵ ਮਾਨਤ ਤਾਹਿ ॥
ਏਕ ਮੂਰਤਿ ਅਨੇਕ ਦਰਸਨ ਕੀਨ ਰੂਪ ਅਨੇਕ ॥
ਖੇਲ ਖੇਲ ਅਖੇਲ ਖੇਲਨ ਅੰਤ ਕੋ ਫਿਰਿ ੲੇਕ ॥੮੧॥
ਦੇਵ ਭੇਵ ਨ ਜਾਨਹੀ ਜਿਹ ਬੇਦ ਅਉਰ ਕਤੇਬ ॥
ਰੂਪ ਰੰਗ ਨ ਜਾਤਿ ਪਾਤਿ ਸੁ ਜਾਨਈ ਕਿਂਹ ਜੇਬ ॥
ਤਾਤ ਮਾਤ ਨ ਜਾਤ ਜਾਕਰ ਜਨਮ ਮਰਨ ਬਿਹੀਨ ॥
ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਬੱਕ੍ਰ ਫਿਰੈ ਚਤੁਰ ਚੱਕ ਮਾਨਹੀ ਪੁਰ ਤੀਨ ॥੮੨॥
ਲੋਕ ਚਉਦਹ ਕੇ ਬਿਖੈ ਜਗ ਜਾਪਹੀ ਜਿਂਹ ਜਾਪ ॥
ਆਦਿ ਦੇਵ ਅਨਾਦਿ ਮੂਰਤਿ ਥਾਪਿਓ ਸਬੈ ਜਿਂਹ ਥਾਪ ॥
ਪਰਮ ਰੂਪ ਪੁਨੀਤ ਮੂਰਤਿ ਪੂਰਨ ਪੁਰਖ ਅਪਾਰ ॥
ਸਰਬ ਬਿਸ੍ਵ ਰਚਿਓ ਸੁਯੰਭਵ ਗੜਨ ਭੰਜਨਹਾਰ ॥੮੩॥
ਕਾਲ ਹੀਨ ਕਲਾ ਸੰਜੁਗਤਿ ਅਕਾਲ ਪੁਰਖ ਅਦੇਸ ॥
ਧਰਮ ਧਾਮ ਸੁ ਭਰਮ ਰਹਿਤ ਅਭੂਤ ਅਲਖ ਅਭੇਸ ॥
ਅੰਗ ਰਾਗ ਨ ਰੰਗ ਜਾਕਹਿ ਜਾਤਿ ਪਾਤਿ ਨ ਨਾਮ ॥
ਗਰਬ ਗੰਜਨ ਦੁਸਟ ਭੰਜਨ ਮੁਕਤਿ ਦਾਇਕ ਕਾਮ ॥੮੪॥
ਆਪ ਰੂਪ ਅਮੀਕ ਅਨ ਉਸਤਤਿ ੲੇਕ ਪੁਰਖ ਅਵਧੂਤ ॥
ਗਰਬ ਗੰਜਨ ਸਰਬ ਭੰਜਨ ਆਦਿ ਰੂਪ ਅਸੂਤ ॥
ਅੰਗ ਹੀਨ ਅਭੰਗ ਅਨਾਤਮ ੲੇਕ ਪੁਰਖ ਅਪਾਰ ॥
ਸਰਬ ਲਾਇਕ ਸਰਬ ਘਾਇਕ ਸਰਬ ਕੋ ਪ੍ਰਿਤਿਪਾਰ ॥੮੫॥
ਸਰਬ ਗੰਤਾ ਸਰਬ ਹੰਤਾ ਸਰਬ ਤੇ ਅਨਭੇਖ ॥
ਸਰਬ ਸਾਸਤ੍ਰ ਨ ਜਾਨਹੀ ਜਿਂਹ ਰੂਪ ਰੰਗੁ ਅਰੁ ਰੇਖ ॥
ਪਰਮ ਬੇਦ ਪੁਰਾਣ ਜਾਕਹਿ ਨੇਤ ਭਾਖਤ ਨਿੱਤ ॥
ਕੋਟਿ ਸਿੰਮ੍ਰਿਤ ਪੁਰਾਨ ਸਾਸਤ੍ਰ ਨ ਆਵਈ ਵਹੁ ਚਿੱਤਿ ॥੮੬॥
ਮਧੁਭਾਰ ਛੰਦ ॥ ਤ੍ਵ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ॥
ਗੁਨ ਗਨ ਉਦਾਰ ॥ ਮਹਿਮਾ ਅਪਾਰ ॥ ਆਸਨ ਅਭੰਗ ॥ ਉਪਮਾ ਅਨੰਗ ॥੮੭॥
ਅਨ ਭਉ ਪ੍ਰਕਾਸ ॥ ਨਿਸ ਦਿਨ ਅਨਾਸ ॥ ਆਜਾਨੁ ਬਾਹੁ ॥ ਸਾਹਾਨ ਸਾਹੁ ॥੮੮॥
ਰਾਜਾਨ ਰਾਜ ॥ ਭਾਨਾਨ ਭਾਨ ॥ ਦੇਵਾਨ ਦੇਵ ॥ ਉਪਮਾ ਮਹਾਨ ॥੮੯॥
ਇੰਦ੍ਰਾਨ ਇੰਦ੍ਰ ॥ ਬਾਲਾਨ ਬਾਲ ॥ ਰੰਕਾਨ ਰੰਕ ॥ ਕਾਲਾਨ ਕਾਲ ॥੯੦॥
ਅਨਭੂਤ ਅੰਗ ॥ ਆਭਾ ਅਭੰਗ ॥ ਗਤਿ ਮਿਤਿ ਅਪਾਰ ॥ ਗੁਨ ਗਨ ਉਦਾਰ ॥੯੧॥
ਮੁਨਿ ਗਨ ਪ੍ਰਨਾਮ ॥ ਨਿਰ ਭੈ ਨਿਕਾਮ ॥ ਅਤਿ ਦੁਤਿ ਪ੍ਰਚੰਡ ॥ ਮਿਤਿ ਗਤਿ ਅਖੰਡ ॥੯੨॥
ਆਲਿਸਯ ਕਰਮ ॥ ਆਦ੍ਰਿਸਯ ਧਰਮ ॥ ਸਰਬਾ ਭਰਣਾਢਯ ॥ ਅਨਡੰਡ ਬਾਢਯ ॥੯੩॥
ਚਾਚਰੀ ਛੰਦ ॥ ਤ੍ਵ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ॥
ਗੋਬਿੰਦੇ॥ ਮੁਕੰਦੇ ॥ ਉਦਾਰੇ ॥ ਅਪਾਰੇ ॥੯੪॥
ਹਰੀਅੰ ॥ ਕਰੀਅੰ ॥ ਨ੍ਰਿਨਾਮੇ ॥ ਅਕਾਮੇ ॥੯੫॥
ਭੁਜੰਗ ਪ੍ਰਯਾਤ ਛੰਦ ॥
ਚੱਤ੍ਰੁ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਕਰਤਾ ॥ ਚੱਤ੍ਰੁ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਹਰਤਾ ॥ ਚੱਤ੍ਰੁ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਦਾਨੇ ॥ ਚੱਤ੍ਰੁ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਜਾਨੇ ॥੯੬॥
ਚੱਤ੍ਰੁ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਵਰਤੀ ॥ ਚੱਤ੍ਰੁ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਭਰਤੀ ॥ ਚੱਤ੍ਰੁ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਪਾਲੇ ॥ ਚੱਤ੍ਰੁ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਕਾਲੇ ॥੯੭॥
ਚੱਤ੍ਰੁ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਪਾਸੇ ॥ ਚੱਤ੍ਰੁ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਵਾਸੇ ॥ ਚੱਤ੍ਰੁ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਮਾਨਯੈ ॥ ਚੱਤ੍ਰੁ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਦਾਨਯੈ ॥੯੮॥
ਚਾਚਰੀ ਛੰਦ ॥
ਨ ਸੱਤ੍ਰੈ ॥ ਨ ਮਿੱਤ੍ਰੈ ॥ ਨ ਭਰਮੰ ॥ ਨ ਭਿੱਤ੍ਰੈ ॥੯੯॥
ਨ ਕਰਮੰ ॥ ਨ ਕਾਏ॥ ਅਜਨਮੰ ॥ ਅਜਾੲੇ ॥੧੦੦॥
ਨ ਚਿੱਤ੍ਰੈ ॥ ਨ ਮਿੱਤ੍ਰੈ ॥ ਪਰੇ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਪਵਿੱਤ੍ਰੈ ॥੧੦੧॥
ਪ੍ਰਿਥੀਸੈ ॥ ਅਦੀਸੈ ॥ ਅਦ੍ਰਿਸੈ ॥ ਅਕ੍ਰਿਸੈ ॥੧੦੨॥
ਭਗਵਤੀ ਛੰਦ ॥ ਤ੍ਵ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ਕਥਤੇ ॥
ਕਿ ਆਛਿਜ ਦੇਸੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਆਭਿਜ ਭੇਸੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਆਗੰਜ ਕਰਮੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਆਭੰਜ ਭਰਮੈ ॥੧੦੩॥
ਕਿ ਆਭਿਜ ਲੋਕੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਆਦਿਤ ਸੋਕੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਅਵਧੂਤ ਬਰਨੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਬਿਭੂਤ ਕਰਨੈ ॥੧੦੪॥
ਕਿ ਰਾਜੰ ਪ੍ਰਭਾ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਧਰਮੰ ਧੁਜਾ ਹੈਂ॥ ਕਿ ਆਸੋਕ ਬਰਨੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬਾ ਅਭਰਨੈ ॥੧੦੫॥
ਕਿ ਜਗਤੰ ਕ੍ਰਿਤੀ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਛਤ੍ਰੰ ਛਤ੍ਰੀ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਬ੍ਰਹਮੰ ਸਰੂਪੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਅਨਭਉ ਅਨੂਪੈ ॥੧੦੬॥
ਕਿ ਆਦਿ ਅਦੇਵ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਆਪਿ ਅਭੇਵ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਚਿੱਤ੍ਰੰ ਬਿਹੀਨੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਏਕੈ ਅਧੀਨੈ ॥੧੦੭॥
ਕਿ ਰੋਜ਼ੀ ਰਜ਼ਾਕੈ ॥ ਰਹੀਮੈ ਰਿਹਾਕੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਪਾਕ ਬਿਅੈਬ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਗ਼ੈਬੁਲ ਗ਼ੈਬ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੦੮॥
ਕਿ ਅਫ਼ਵੁਲ ਗੁਨਾਹ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਸ਼ਾਹਾਨ ਸ਼ਾਹ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਕਾਰਨ ਕੁਨਿੰਦ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਰੋਜ਼ੀ ਦਿਹੰਦ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੦੯॥
ਕਿ ਰਾਜ਼ਕ ਰਹੀਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਕਰਮੰ ਕਰੀਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੰ ਕਲੀ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੰ ਦਲੀ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੧੦॥
ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਮਾਨਿਯੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਦਾਨਿਯੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਗਉਨੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਭਉਨੈ ॥੧੧੧॥
ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਦੇਸੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਭੇਸੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਰਾਜੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਸਾਜੈ ॥੧੧੨॥
ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਦੀਨੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਲੀਨੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਜਾਹੋ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਭਾਹੋ ॥੧੧੩॥
ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਦੇਸੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਭੇਸੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਕਾਲੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਪਾਲੈ ॥੧੧੪॥
ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਹੰਤਾ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਗੰਤਾ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਭੇਖੀ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਪੇਖੀ ॥੧੧੫॥
ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਕਾਜੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਰਾਜੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਸੋਖੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਪੋਖੈ ॥੧੧੬॥
ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਤ੍ਰਾਣੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਪ੍ਰਾਣੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਦੇਸੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਭੇਸੈ ॥੧੧੭॥
ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਮਾਨਿਯੈਂ ॥ ਸਦੈਵੰ ਪ੍ਰਧਾਨਿਯੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਜਾਪਿਯੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਥਾਪਿਯੈ ॥੧੧੮॥
ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਭਾਨੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਮਾਨੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਇੰਦ੍ਰੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਰਬੱਤ੍ਰ ਚੰਦ੍ਰੈ ॥੧੧੯॥
ਕਿ ਸਰਬੰ ਕਲੀਮੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਪਰਮੰ ਫ਼ਹੀਮੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਆਕਿਲ ਅਲਾਮੈ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਾਹਿਬ ਕਲਾਮੈ ॥੧੨੦॥
ਕਿ ਹੁਸਨਲ ਵਜੂ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਤਮਾਮੁਲ ਰੁਜੂ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਹਮੇਸੁਲ ਸਲਾਮੈਂ ॥ ਸਲੀਖਤ ਮੁਦਾਮੈਂ ॥੧੨੧॥
ਗ਼ਨੀਮੁਲ ਸ਼ਿਕਸਤੈ ॥ ਗ਼ਰੀਬੁਲ ਪਰਸਤੈ ॥ ਬਿਲੰਦੁਲ ਮਕਾਨੈਂ ॥ ਜ਼ਮੀਨੁਲ ਜ਼ਮਾਨੈਂ ॥੧੨੨॥
ਤਮੀਜ਼ੁਲ ਤਮਾਮੈਂ ॥ ਰੁਜੂਅਲ ਨਿਧਾਨੈਂ ॥ ਹਰੀਫੁਲ ਅਜੀਮੈਂ ॥ ਰਜ਼ਾਇਕ ਯਕੀਨੈਂ ॥੧੨੩॥
ਅਨੇਕੁਲ ਤਰੰਗ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੇਦ ਹੈਂ ਅਭੰਗ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਜ਼ੀਜ਼ੁਲ ਨਿਵਾਜ਼ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਗ਼ਨੀਮੁਲ ਖ਼ਿਰਾਜ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੨੪॥
ਨਿਰੁਕਤ ਸਰੂਪ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਤ੍ਰਿਮੁਕਤਿ ਬਿਭੂਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਪ੍ਰਭੁਗਤਿ ਪ੍ਰਭਾ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸੁਜੁਗਤਿ ਸੁਧਾ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੨੫॥
ਸਦੈਵੰ ਸਰੂਪ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੇਦੀ ਅਨੂਪ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਮਸਤੋ ਪਰਾਜ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਦਾ ਸਰਬ ਸਾਜ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੨੬॥
ਸਮਸਤੁਲ ਸਲਾਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਦੈਵਲ ਅਕਾਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਨ੍ਰਿਬਾਧ ਸਰੂਪ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਗਾਧ ਹੈਂ ਅਨੂਪ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੨੭॥
ਓਅੰ ਆਦਿ ਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਅਨਾਦਿ ਸਰੂਪੈ ॥ ਅਨੰਗੀ ਅਨਾਮੇ ॥ ਤ੍ਰਿਭੰਗੀ ਤ੍ਰਿਕਾਮੇ ॥੧੨੮॥
ਤ੍ਰਿਬਰਗੰ ਤ੍ਰਿਬਾਧੇ ॥ ਅਗੰਜੇ ਅਗਾਧੇ ॥ ਸੁਭੰ ਸਰਬ ਭਾਗੇ ॥ ਸੁ ਸਰਬਾ ਅਨੁਰਾਗੇ॥੧੨੯॥
ਤ੍ਰਿਭੁਗਤ ਸਰੂਪ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਛਿੱਜ ਹੈਂ ਅਛੂਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਨਰਕੰ ਪ੍ਰਣਾਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਪ੍ਰਿਥੀਉਲ ਪ੍ਰਵਾਸ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੩੦॥
ਨਿਰੁਕੱਤ ਪ੍ਰਭਾ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਦੈਵੰ ਸਦਾ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਬਿਭੁਗਤਿ ਸਰੂਪ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਪ੍ਰਜੁਗਤਿ ਅਨੂਪ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੩੧॥
ਨਿਰੁਕੱਤ ਸਦਾ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਬਿਭੁਗਤਿ ਪ੍ਰਭਾ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਨਉਕਤਿ ਸਰੂਪ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਪ੍ਰਜੁਗਤਿ ਅਨੂਪ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੩੨॥
ਚਾਚਰੀ ਛੰਦ ॥
ਅਭੰਗ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਨੰਗ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੇਖ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਲੇਖ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੩੩॥
ਅਭਰਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਕਰਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਨਾਦਿ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਜੁਗਾਦਿ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੩੪॥
ਅਜੈ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਬੈ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੂਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਧੂਤ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੩੫॥
ਅਨਾਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਉਦਾਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਧੰਧ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਬੰਧ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੩੬॥
ਅਭਗਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਬਿਰਕਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਨਾਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਪ੍ਰਕਾਸ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੩੭॥
ਨਿਚਿੰਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸੁਨਿੰਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਲਿੱਖ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਦਿੱਖ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੩੮॥
ਅਲੇਖ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਭੇਖ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਢਾਹ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਗਾਹ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੩੯॥
ਅਸੰਭ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਗੰਭ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਨੀਲ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਨਾਦਿ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੪੦॥
ਅਨਿੱਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸੁ ਨਿੱਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਜਾਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਜਾਦਿ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੪੧॥
ਚਰਪਟ ਛੰਦ ॥ ਤ੍ਵ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ॥
ਸਰਬੰ ਹੰਤਾ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਗੰਤਾ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਖਿਆਤਾ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਗਿਆਤਾ ॥੧੪੨॥
ਸਰਬੰ ਹਰਤਾ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਕਰਤਾ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਪ੍ਰਾਣੰ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਤ੍ਰਾਣੰ ॥੧੪੩॥
ਸਰਬੰ ਕਰਮੰ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਧਰਮੰ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਜੁਗਤਾ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਮੁਕਤਾ ॥੧੪੪॥
ਰਸਾਵਲ ਛੰਦ ॥ ਤ੍ਵ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ॥
ਨਮੋ ਨਰਕ ਨਾਸੇ ॥ ਸਦੈਵੰ ਪ੍ਰਕਾਸੇ ॥ ਅਨੰਗੰ ਸਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਅਭੰਗੰ ਬਿਭੂਤੇ ॥੧੪੫॥
ਪ੍ਰਮਾਥੰ ਪ੍ਰਮਾਥੇ ॥ ਸਦਾ ਸਰਬ ਸਾਥੇ ॥ ਅਗਾਧ ਸਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਨ੍ਰਿਬਾਧ ਬਿਭੂਤੇ ॥੧੪੬॥
ਅਨੰਗੀ ਅਨਾਮੇ ॥ ਤ੍ਰਿਭੰਗੀ ਤ੍ਰਿਕਾਮੇ ॥ ਨ੍ਰਿਭੰਗੀ ਸਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਸਰਬੰਗੀ ਅਨੂਪੇ ॥੧੪੭॥
ਨ ਪੋਤ੍ਰੈ ਨ ਪੁਤ੍ਰੈ ॥ ਨ ਸੱਤ੍ਰੈ ਨ ਮਿੱਤ੍ਰੈ ॥ ਨ ਤਾਤੈ ਨ ਮਾਤੈ ॥ ਨ ਜਾਤੈ ਨ ਪਾਤੈ ॥੧੪੮॥
ਨ੍ਰਿਸਾਕੰ ਸਰੀਕ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਮਿਤੋ ਅਮੀਕ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਦੈਵੰ ਪ੍ਰਭਾ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਜੈ ਹੈਂ ਅਜਾ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੪੯॥
ਭਗਵਤੀ ਛੰਦ ॥ ਤ੍ਵ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ॥
ਕਿ ਜ਼ਾਹਰ ਜ਼ਹੂਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਹਾਜ਼ਰ ਹਜ਼ੂਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਹਮੇਸੁਲ ਸਲਾਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਮਸਤੁਲ ਕਲਾਮ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੫੦॥
ਕਿ ਸਾਹਿਬ ਦਿਮਾਗ਼ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਹੁਸਨਲ ਚਰਾਗ਼ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਕਾਮਲ ਕਰੀਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਰਾਜ਼ਕ ਰਹੀਮ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੫੧॥
ਕਿ ਰੋਜ਼ੀ ਦਿਹਿੰਦ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਰਾਜ਼ਕ ਰਹਿੰਦ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਰੀਮੁਲ ਕਮਾਲ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਹੁਸਨਲ ਜਮਾਲ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੫੨॥
ਗ਼ਨੀਮੁਲ ਖ਼ਿਰਾਜ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਗ਼ਰੀਬੁਲ ਨਿਵਾਜ਼ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਹਰੀਫੁਲ ਸ਼ਿਕੰਨ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਹਿਰਾਸੁਲ ਫਿਕੰਨ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੫੩॥
ਕਲੰਕੰ ਪੁਰਣਾਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਮਸਤੁਲ ਨਿਵਾਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਗੰਜੁਲ ਗਨੀਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਰਜਾਇਕ ਰਹੀਮ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੫੪॥
ਸਮਸਤੁਲ ਜੁਬਾਂ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਸਾਹਿਬ ਕਿਰਾਂ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਨਰਕੰ ਪ੍ਰਣਾਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਬਹਿਸਤੁਲ ਨਿਵਾਸ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੫੫॥
ਕਿ ਸਰਬੁਲ ਗਵੰਨ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਹਮੇਸੁਲ ਰਵੰਨ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਤਮਾਮੁਲ ਤਮੀਜ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਮਸਤੁਲ ਅਜੀਜ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੫੬॥
ਪਰੰ ਪਰਮ ਈਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਮਸਤੁਲ ਅਦੀਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਦੇਸੁਲ ਅਲੇਖ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਹਮੇਸੁਲ ਅਭੇਖ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੫੭॥
ਜ਼ਿਮੀਨੁਲ ਜ਼ਮਾ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਮੀਕੁਲ ਇਮਾ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਰੀਮੁਲ ਕਮਾਲ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਜੁਰਅਤਿ ਜਮਾਲ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੫੮॥
ਕਿ ਅਚਲੰ ਪ੍ਰਕਾਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਅਮਿਤੋ ਸੁਬਾਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਅਜਬ ਸਰੂਪ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਅਮਿਤੋ ਬਿਭੂਤ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੫੯॥
ਕਿ ਅਮਿਤੋ ਪਸਾ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਆਤਮ ਪ੍ਰਭਾ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਅਚਲੰ ਅਨੰਗ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਿ ਅਮਿਤੋ ਅਭੰਗ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੬੦॥
ਮਧੁਭਾਰ ਛੰਦ ॥ ਤ੍ਵ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ॥
ਮੁਨਿ ਮਨਿ ਪ੍ਰਨਾਮ ॥ ਗੁਨਿ ਗਨ ਮੁਦਾਮ ॥ ਅਰਿ ਬਰ ਅਗੰਜ ॥ ਹਰਿ ਨਰ ਪ੍ਰਭੰਜ ॥੧੬੧॥
ਅਨ ਗਨ ਪ੍ਰਨਾਮ ॥ ਮੁਨਿ ਮਨਿ ਸਲਾਮ ॥ ਹਰਿ ਨਰ ਅਖੰਡ ॥ ਬਰ ਨਰ ਅਮੰਡ ॥੧੬੨॥
ਅਨ ਭਵ ਅਨਾਸ ॥ ਮੁਨਿ ਮਨਿ ਪ੍ਰਕਾਸ ॥ ਗੁਨਿ ਗਨ ਪ੍ਰਨਾਮ ॥ ਜਲ ਥਲ ਮੁਦਾਮ ॥੧੬੩॥
ਅਨ ਛਿੱਜ ਅੰਗ ॥ ਆਸਨ ਅਭੰਗ ॥ ਉਪਮਾ ਅਪਾਰ ॥ ਗਤਿ ਮਿਤਿ ਉਦਾਰ ॥੧੬੪॥
ਜਲ ਥਲ ਅਮੰਡ ॥ ਦਿਸ ਵਿਸ ਅਭੰਡ ॥ ਜਲ ਥਲ ਮਹੰਤ ॥ ਦਿਸ ਵਿਸ ਬਿਅੰਤ ॥੧੬੫॥
ਅਨ ਭਵ ਅਨਾਸ ॥ ਧ੍ਰਿਤ ਧਰ ਧੁਰਾਸ ॥ ਆ ਜਾਨ ਬਾਹੁ ॥ ੲੇਕੈ ਸਦਾਹੁ ॥੧੬੬॥
ਓਅੰ ਕਾਰ ਆਦਿ ॥ ਕਥ ਨੀ ਅਨਾਦਿ ॥ ਖਲ ਖੰਡ ਖਿਆਲ ॥ ਗੁਰ ਬਰ ਅਕਾਲ ॥੧੬੭॥
ਘਰ ਘਰਿ ਪ੍ਰਨਾਮ ॥ ਚਿਤ ਚਰਨ ਨਾਮ ॥ ਅਨ ਛਿੱਜ ਗਾਤ ॥ ਆ ਜਿਜ ਨ ਬਾਤ ॥੧੬੮॥
ਅਨ ਝੰਝ ਗਾਤ ॥ ਅਨ ਰੰਜ ਬਾਤ ॥ ਅਨ ਟੁਟ ਭੰਡਾਰ ॥ ਅਨ ਠਟ ਅਪਾਰ ॥੧੬੯॥
ਆ ਡੀਠ ਧਰਮ ॥ ਅਤਿ ਢੀਠ ਕਰਮ ॥ ਅਣ ਬ੍ਰਣ ਅਨੰਤ ॥ ਦਾ ਤਾ ਮਹੰਤ ॥੧੭੦॥
ਹਰਿ ਬੋਲ ਮਨਾ ਛੰਦ ॥ ਤ੍ਵ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ॥
ਕਰੁਣਾਲਯ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਰਿ ਘਾਲਯ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਖਲ ਖੰਡਨ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਮਹਿ ਮੰਡਨ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੭੧॥
ਜਗਤੇਸ੍ਵਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਪਰਮੇਸ੍ਵਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਲਿ ਕਾਰਣ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਰਬ ਉਬਾਰਣ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੭੨॥
ਧ੍ਰਿਤ ਕੇ ਧਰਣ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਜਗ ਕੇ ਕਰਨ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਮਨ ਮਾਨਿਯ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਜਗ ਜਾਨਿਯ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੭੩॥
ਸਰਬੰ ਭਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਰਬੰ ਕਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਰਬ ਪਾਸਿਯ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਰਬ ਨਾਸਿਯ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੭੪॥
ਕਰੁਣਾਕਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਬਿਸ੍ਵੰਭਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਰਬੇਸ੍ਵਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਜਗਤੇਸ੍ਵਰ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੭੫॥
ਬ੍ਰਹਮੰਡਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਖਲ ਖੰਡਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਪਰ ਤੇ ਪਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਰੁਣਾਕਰ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੭੬॥
ਅਜਪਾ ਜਪ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਥਪਾ ਥਪ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਕ੍ਰਿਤਾ ਕ੍ਰਿਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਮ੍ਰਿਤਾ ਮ੍ਰਿਤ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੭੭॥
ਅਮ੍ਰਿਤਾ ਮ੍ਰਿਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਰੁਣਾ ਕ੍ਰਿਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਕ੍ਰਿਤਾ ਕ੍ਰਿਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਧਰਣੀ ਧ੍ਰਿਤ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੭੮॥
ਅਮਿਤੇਸ੍ਵਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਪਰਮੇਸ੍ਵਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਕ੍ਰਿਤਾ ਕ੍ਰਿਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਮ੍ਰਿਤਾ ਮ੍ਰਿਤ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੭੯॥
ਅਜਬਾ ਕ੍ਰਿਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਮ੍ਰਿਤਾ ਅਮ੍ਰਿਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਨਰ ਨਾਇਕ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਖਲ ਘਾਇਕ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੮੦॥
ਬਿਸ੍ਵੰਭਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਰੁਣਾਲਯ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਨ੍ਰਿਪ ਨਾਇਕ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਰਬ ਪਾਇਕ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੮੧॥
ਭਵ ਭੰਜਨ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਅਰਿ ਗੰਜਨ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਰਿਪੁ ਤਾਪਨ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਜਪੁ ਜਾਪਨ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੮੨॥
ਅਕਲੰ ਕ੍ਰਿਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਰਬਾ ਕ੍ਰਿਤ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਕਰਤਾ ਕਰ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਹਰਤਾ ਹਰਿ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੮੩॥
ਪਰਮਾਤਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਸਰਬਾਤਮ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਆਤਮ ਬਸ ਹੈਂ ॥ ਜਸ ਕੇ ਜਸ ਹੈਂ ॥੧੮੪॥
ਭੁਜੰਗ ਪ੍ਰਯਾਤ ਛੰਦ ॥
ਨਮੋ ਸੂਰਜ ਸੂਰਜੇ ਨਮੋ ਚੰਦ੍ਰ ਚੰਦ੍ਰੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਰਾਜ ਰਾਜੇ ਨਮੋ ਇੰਦ੍ਰ ਇੰਦ੍ਰੇ ॥
ਨਮੋ ਅੰਧਕਾਰੇ ਨਮੋ ਤੇਜ ਤੇਜੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਬਿ੍ਰੰਦ ਬਿ੍ਰੰਦੇ ਨਮੋ ਬੀਜ ਬੀਜੇ ॥੧੮੫॥
ਨਮੋ ਰਾਜਸੰ ਤਾਮਸੰ ਸਾਂਤ ਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਪਰਮ ਤੱਤੰ ਅਤੱਤੰ ਸਰੂਪੇ ॥
ਨਮੋ ਜੋਗ ਜੋਗੇ ਨਮੋ ਗਿਆਨ ਗਿਆਨੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਮੰਤ੍ਰ ਮੰਤ੍ਰੇ ਨਮੋ ਧਿਆਨ ਧਿਆਨੇ ॥੧੮੬॥
ਨਮੋ ਜੁਧ ਜੁਧੇ ਨਮੋ ਗਿਆਨ ਗਿਆਨੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਭੋਜ ਭੋਜੇ ਨਮੋ ਪਾਨ ਪਾਨੇ ॥
ਨਮੋ ਕਲਹ ਕਰਤਾ ਨਮੋ ਸਾਂਤ ਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਇੰਦ੍ਰ ਇੰਦ੍ਰੇ ਅਨਾਦੰ ਬਿਭੂਤੇ ॥੧੮੭॥
ਕਲੰਕਾਰ ਰੂਪੇ ਅਲੰਕਾਰ ਅਲੰਕੇ ॥ ਨਮੋ ਆਸ ਆਸੇ ਨਮੋ ਬਾਂਕ ਬੰਕੇ ॥
ਅਭੰਗੀ ਸਰੂਪੇ ਅਨੰਗੀ ਅਨਾਮੇ ॥ ਤ੍ਰਿਭੰਗੀ ਤ੍ਰਿਕਾਲੇ ਅਨੰਗੀ ਅਕਾਮੇ ॥੧੮੮॥
ਏਕ ਅਛਰੀ ਛੰਦ ॥
ਅਜੈ ॥ ਅਲੈ ॥ ਅਭੈ ॥ ਅਬੈ ॥੧੮੯॥
ਅਭੂ ॥ ਅਜੂ ॥ ਅਨਾਸ ॥ ਅਕਾਸ ॥੧੯੦॥
ਅਗੰਜ ॥ ਅਭੰਜ ॥ ਅਲੱਖ ॥ ਅਭੱਖ ॥੧੯੧॥
ਅਕਾਲ ॥ ਦਿਆਲ ॥ ਅਲੇਖ ॥ ਅਭੇਖ ॥੧੯੨॥
ਅਨਾਮ ॥ ਅਕਾਮ ॥ ਅਗਾਹ ॥ ਅਢਾਹ ॥੧੯੩॥
ਅਨਾਥੇ ॥ ਪ੍ਰਮਾਥੇ ॥ ਅਜੋਨੀ ॥ ਅਮੋਨੀ ॥੧੯੪॥
ਨ ਰਾਗੇ ॥ ਨ ਰੰਗੇ ॥ ਨ ਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਨ ਰੇਖੇ ॥੧੯੫॥
ਅਕਰਮੰ ॥ ਅਭਰਮੰ ॥ ਅਗੰਜੇ ॥ ਅਲੇਖੇ ॥੧੯੬॥
ਭੁਜੰਗ ਪ੍ਰਯਾਤ ਛੰਦ ॥
ਨਮਸਤੁਲ ਪ੍ਰਣਾਮੇ ਸਮਸਤੁਲ ਪ੍ਰਣਾਸੇ ॥ ਅਗੰਜੁਲ ਅਨਾਮੇ ਸਮਸਤੁਲ ਨਿਵਾਸੇ ॥
ਨ੍ਰਿਕਾਮੰ ਬਿਭੂਤੇ ਸਮਸਤੁਲ ਸਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਕੁਕਰਮੰ ਪੁਰਣਾਸੀ ਸੁਧਰਮੰ ਬਿਭੂਤੇ ॥੧੯੭॥
ਸਦਾ ਸੱਚਿਦਾਨੰਦ ਸੱਤ੍ਰੰ ਪ੍ਰਣਾਸੀ ॥ ਕਰੀਮੁਲ ਕੁਨਿੰਦਾ ਸਮਸਤੁਲ ਨਿਵਾਸੀ ॥
ਅਜਾਇਬ ਬਿਭੂਤੇ ਗਜਾਇਬ ਗਨੀਮੇ ॥ ਹਰੀਅੰ ਕਰੀਅੰ ਕਰੀਮੁਲ ਰਹੀਮੇ ॥੧੯੮॥
ਚੱਤ੍ਰ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਵਰਤੀ ਚੱਤ੍ਰ ਚੱਕ੍ਰ ਭੁਗਤੇ ॥ ਸੁਯੰਭਵ ਸੁਭੰ ਸਰਬਦਾ ਸਰਬ ਜੁਗਤੇ ॥
ਦੁਕਾਲੰ ਪ੍ਰਣਾਸੀ ਦਿਆਲੰ ਸਰੂਪੇ ॥ ਸਦਾ ਅੰਗ ਸੰਗੇ ਅਭੰਗੰ ਬਿਭੂਤੇ ॥੧੯੯॥</string>
</resources>
```

I want to format the TextView the same way this text is formatted.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51733275/3022836

Comment: You might want to consider [Paginating text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31837840/3290339)

Comment: I feel like you might want to look into using a ``WebView`` instead. Store the text in one or more files (not a string resource), mark it up using HTML, and then use CSS to control how it looks, how it's laid out etc. I don't know how easy it is to work with ``TextView``s for specific formatting, but HTML/CSS was made for this kind of thing, it's really flexible

Comment: @cactustictacs i will surely give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use \n in the string to make a new line.

To do more special formatting,

- set a style for your TextView or
- set the typeface (e.g. serif, arial)
- set the text style (e.g. italic, bold)

To use a larger string, you need to enter it into a .txt-File (see this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51733275/14669853)

Comment: thanks for the answer , but when i am using \n for a new line, its converting it into gurmukhi font and showing random words

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the AAPT/AAPT2 (Android Asset Packaging Tool) which processes your app’s resources and replaces them with the STRING_TOO_LARGE value when it finds a large string.

The STRING_TOO_LARGE issue is pretty easy to reproduce and may happen to you quite unexpectedly. The easiest way is to add a string resource to your app that is longer than 0x7FFF = 32767 characters and then displaying it e.g. in a TextView.